# Can you initialize an Enum value from the name of its case (*not* its RawValue?)

Tags: swift, enums, initialization

Consider this enumeration (note its type is `Int`)

```
enum MyTestEnum : Int{
    case one     = 1
    case eight   = 8
    case unknown = -1
}
```

You can easily initialize a version of this based on the raw value, like so...

```
let value = MyTestEnum(rawValue:-1)
```

I'm trying to find out if it can be initialized with a string representation of the case name itself (again, not the raw value, but the word after 'case') like so...

```
let value = MyTestEnum(caseName:"eight")
```

Note: I want this to work with *any* enum if possible, regardless of its raw value type.  For instance, this one...

```
enum MyOtherEnum{
    case xxx
    case yyy
    case zzz
}

let value = MyOtherEnum(caseName:"xxx")
```

So can this be done?

Thoughts:

- I think Swift has a way to instantiate a class given a string representing the fully-qualified class-name.  Perhaps something similar can be used here.

Comment: Is this for the purpose of JSON (de)seriailzation?

Comment: No, it's for general-purpose (we do it in other languages without issue) but the particular use-case that has me trying this is writing an Xcode extension and using an enumeration's case names to be the command IDs, and the string rawValue to be the label.  When we get the command back from the user, we get the command ID so I'm trying to re-create the case so I can use it in a switch.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using a `String` rawValue? Do you need the 8, 2, -1,... ?

Comment: As mentioned above, there may not be any raw value, let alone a string.  Look at MyOtherEnum above.  It doesn't have a string raw value, but it does have the case names 'xxx', 'yyy' and 'zzz'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Swift 4.2, this is quite easy to do now using `CaseIterable`.

```
enum MyOtherEnum: CaseIterable {
    case xxx
    case yyy
    case zzz
    
    init?(caseName: String) {
        for value in MyOtherEnum.allCases where "\(value)" == caseName {
            self = value
            return
        }
        
        return nil
    }
}

enum MyTestEnum: Int, CaseIterable{
    case one     = 1
    case eight   = 8
    case unknown = -1
    
    init?(caseName: String) {
        for value in MyTestEnum.allCases where "\(value)" == caseName {
            self = value
            return
        }
        
        return nil
    }
}
```

What I am doing here is creating a failable initializer which iterates through all potential cases, testing to see if `"\(value)"` (which returns the name for that potential case) matches the `caseName` argument passed in to the initializer.

When a match is found, `self` is set and the loop ends. Otherwise, `nil` is returned for the call.

Below, are two working and two failing examples:

```
let myOtherEnum = MyOtherEnum(caseName:"xxx")
print(myOtherEnum) // MyOtherEnum.xxx

let myTestEnum = MyTestEnum(caseName:"eight")
print(myTestEnum?.rawValue) // 8

let myOtherEnumFail = MyOtherEnum(caseName:"aaa")
print(myOtherEnumFail) // nil

let myTestEnumFail = MyTestEnum(caseName:"ten")
print(myTestEnumFail) // nil
```

Comment: Only downside of this approach is it only works for enums which we own as you can't add `CaseIterable` to enums via a protocol. It has to be added at the original point of definition.

Comment: Just another follow-up.  How about changing it to `guard let match = Self.allCases.first(where: {"\($0)" == caseName}) else { return nil }` and then `self = match` on the next line? (I *really* hate that you can't have multi-line code in comments.  Ugh!!)

Answer (score 3):

Based on CodeBender's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53918440/5806210) here is a nice extension for this case

```
extension CaseIterable {

    ///Note: case value and name can be different
    init?(caseName: String) {
        for v in Self.allCases where "\(v)" == caseName {
            self = v
            return
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the for? You only iterate once.

Comment: @Cristik You are correct in that other options could be used, such as a filter on the array. I have seen in the past where a `for` loop out performs a `filter`, but YMMV based upon your use case. Plus, other options may be more verbose for this.

Comment: `filter` suffers from another same issue, it iterates through the whole array without being needed to. What I wanted to say is that you could've use a better and more readable construct like `first(where:)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with custom initializer

```
extension MyTestEnum {
    public static func allValues() -> [MyTestEnum] {
        let retVal = AnySequence { () -> AnyIterator<MyTestEnum> in
            var raw = 0
            return AnyIterator {
                let current = withUnsafePointer(to: &raw) {
                    $0.withMemoryRebound(to: MyTestEnum.self, capacity: 1) { $0.pointee }
                }
                guard current.hashValue == raw else { return nil }
                raw += 1
                return current
            }
        }

        return [MyTestEnum](retVal)
    }

    init?(caseName: String){
        for v in MyTestEnum.allValues() {
            if "\(v)" == caseName {
                self = v
                return
            }
        }
        self = MyTestEnum.unknown
    }
}

let test = MyTestEnum(caseName: "eight")
```

or simple manually all your case :)

```
extension MyTestEnum {
 init?(caseName: String){
   switch caseName {
     case "eight": self.init(rawValue: 8)
     case "one": self.init(rawValue: 1)
     default: self.init(rawValue: -1)
   }
 }
}

let test1 = MyTestEnum(caseName: "eight") 
let test2 = MyTestEnum(rawValue: 1)
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: I would just use `self = .eight`, `self = .one`, etc. The connection to raw values gets confusing (for enums whose cases aren't literally named after their raw values)

Comment: This doesn't really solve our problem.  The problem isn't just initializing from a string, it's initializing from an existing name.  With this, we would have to maintain the list inside the init statement. (As a side note, you don't need the init calls with raw values as you could just specify the value directly since you're already doing it manually.)

Comment: @Alexander wow, really??? i can't use self = .eight in init method, i use swift 4, what version of swift are you using?

Comment: @SuaLe http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/5a31e561e1498b18dac8b1d8

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like your want your enum cases to have raw `Int` values *and* raw `String` values. It's not strictly possible to do this, but perhaps this comes close:

```
enum MyTestEnum : String {
    case one
    case eight
    case unknown

    var intValue: Int {
        switch self {
        case one: return 1
        case eight: return 8
        case unknown: return -1
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can initialize from case names, but you can also retrieve an `intValue` when needed. (If needed, you could easily add a failable initializer to allow initialization from integers as well.)

Comment: Not quite.  I think I confused things by mentioning raw values. Just forget them altogether. Again, I'm trying to create an instance of MyTestEnum.eight from the string "eight" since that's the name of the case.  Make sense?

Comment: Yes, this solution does that--if you need no integer raw values, then just leave off the `intValue` computed property. Simply having a raw value of `String` will automatically allow you to initialize your cases by name.

Comment: (If your question, however, is "can I initialize enums by name *without* giving them a raw value of `String`?" then the answer is "Nope. Not unless you want to write the initializer yourself.")

Comment: Your statement "imply having a raw value of String will automatically allow you to initialize your cases by name" is not really true.  It initializes by it's raw value.  It's just if you don't explicitly give it one, it uses the case name, but if you do (and in our case a lot of times we do) you can't use that approach.  That's actually what we're trying to get around.

Comment: What about reflection, or type-instance-creation from a string representation?  You can do it with other classes. Perhaps you can also do it for enums.